# iOS: Detect if WIFI has been authenticated?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, wifi

There are times when you connect to a Starbucks Wifi, the auth page does not automatically pop up. The auth page (the one where you press "Agree" to the Wifi terms) shows up when you start using Safari. Is there any way to detect if the auth page has already been shown on the device in my app?

Comment: Have you looked at the Reachability sample provided by Apple? If you use it to ping www.apple.com, it will prompt your user to accept the terms of that hotspot (at least, it used to; might have changed). It MUST ping www.apple.com, though: no other domain will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to download a file somewhere, that you know will never move ([www.google.com](http://www.google.com)), and whose contents you already know (thats the hard part).

Compare the downloaded content with the content that should be downloaded, and you'll know you're on some authentication page or not.

Comment: I need a worldwide solution. I have no clue what's going on with China. Can people in China access www.google.com?

Comment: You can create a file on your own server too... ping.html

Comment: That technique doesn't guarantee it works. I'm testing this at a Starbucks WiFi in Canada, and a JSON request over HTTP or HTTPS returns me the good response (in JSON). Opening Safari to Google works (I don't get the redirect). However, if I try to open staples.ca or apple.com, I get the redirect. Some of my service endpoints go through, some don't.

Comment: If your app is going to be accessed worldwide, you can set up a service in your server that returns a specific (custom) header in the response and try to access it from a wifi connection. If you get the response header info, you know that it is a authenticated wifi. Otherwise, you can know that there are other reasons why your service is being denied, one of which being the wifi authentication problem. Works!